# C# Programming Structs with spaces? How to store a lot of properties of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, struct, enums

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I don't know what to look up. I was hoping someone could clear this up for me.  Let's say I want to create a car class.  the car class is going to have a make, model, type, color. The values would never change. Unless there's a way to store the answers in a file and change them and still follow the requirements below.

Requirements

1. I would like to refer to the properties in code.  `Car.Type.Sedan`, `Car.Color.CandyAppleRed`
2. I would theoretically need an admin section so I'd like to be able to bind the exact properties to a drop down list so a user could select a single property.
3. When I implement the answers on a web page, it would need to be generated from the code
   Car Type: Sedan
   Car Color: Candy Apple Red
4. I'd like to store the cars values in a database, with an int if possible.

An enum seems the best solution, the ONLY problem is there can't be spaces in an enum.  so Candy Apple Red would show up in the dropdownlist and in the page as CandyAppleRed.

I've struggled with this for awhile.  Can someone pleas help me out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dropdowns submit values, but also have display values. Nothing stops you from showing the drop down list value as "Candy Apple Red" but having the actual submitted value be the no-space name or an integer.

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Candy Apple Red</option>
    *OR*
    <option value="CandyAppleRed">Candy Apple Red</option>
</select>
```

More on select lists: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: Yes but I would need to manually create these dropdowns.  I was looking for a more databound automatic solution.  ddlCarTypes.Datasource = Car.Types;

Comment: Ok,  I found this http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/associating-strings-with-enums-in-c, the person has a solution to the exact same problem I'm having, but it seems a little crazy that you have to create a static method to decipher the right value and do a foreach loop to populate the dropdownlist. Just seems like there HAS to be a way to create a simple enum CarColors { Candy Apple Red, Green, Teal Blue }.  I do this constantly in code,  I usually solve it by creating a table in the DB for a few values and creating a class.  Seems horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If the drop down is on a website, I suppose you could populate it with the enum values but parse them before assigning them qr programmatically add spaces before capital letters or something.

```
CandyApple > Candy Apple
```

If I were going to do this, though, I would just use static string constants in some static class *almost* like an enumerable.

```
class CarProperties
{
    const string Sedan = "Sedan";
    const string CandyAppleRed = "Candy Apple Red";
}
```

Not that I would be eager to do this, but it would work. :p

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  What I ended up doing seems kind of hackish, but I am just going to make the enum values with underscores, Candy_Apple_Red, Teal_Blue then replace the underscore.  Seems the least amount of load compared to all of the solutions I've found.